# DATEADD рабочие дни (без циклов)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Пробую через этот запрос получить нужную дату, но не для всех случаев подходит

```
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME
DECLARE @DaysToAdd INT
SET @StartDate = '2018/03/3'
SET @DaysToAdd =2

SELECT DATEADD(dd, (@DaysToAdd % 5) + CASE ((@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(weekday, @StartDate) + (@DaysToAdd % 5)) % 7)
                                                     WHEN 0 THEN 2
                                                     WHEN 1 THEN 1
                                                     ELSE 0 END 
                                                     , DATEADD(week, (@DaysToAdd / 5), @StartDate))
```

**На входе** - дата и количество рабочих дней, которые необходимо сложить, 
**на выходе** - дата без учета выходных дней (сб, вс).
Приведенный пример кода не совсем корректно считает для кейса '2018/03/3' + 2 рабочих дня дня возвращает 5е число а не 6е

Comment: Опишите задание более подробно? (что мы получаем на вход и что должно быть на выходе)

Comment: На входе - дата и количество рабочих дней, которые необходимо сложить, на выходе - дата без учета выходных дней (сб, вс).

Comment: A 8 марта 2018 года, например, должно считаться рабочим днём, или нет?

Comment: А какой смысл несёт в себе эта часть запроса: DATEADD(week, (@DaysToAdd / 5), @StartDate)?

Comment: если праздник в будень день то рабочий, не считаем только сб и вс

Comment: ну если я хочу добавить к сегодняшней дате  20 будних дней, какое число получится? мне нужно узнать количество недель чтоб учесть в рассчете

Comment: а по какой причине вы не хотите использовать циклы?

Comment: решение с использованием циклов как раз не подходит в силу того, что рассчет нужно произвести в теле sql инструкции, с применением циклов придется выносить в отдельню функцию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы не отказывался от применения циклов, считать недели и прописывать кучу IF нет смысла. Гораздо правильнее на мой взгляд проверять является ли день выходным и прибавлять его или нет в зависимости от принадлежности.

```
DECLARE @DateStart datetime, @DateEnd datetime, @CounctDays int
-- сюда количество дней которое надо добавить
SET @CounctDays = 2

--примем за начало - сегодня + сбросим время на 0:00 (опционально) если не надо то просто getdate()
SET @DateStart =convert(nvarchar,getdate(),112)
SELECT @DateStart

-- если @@DATEFIRST = 7, значит выходные в РФ 7 и 1
IF @@DATEFIRST = 7
BEGIN
    WHILE @CounctDays>0
    BEGIN
        IF DATEPART(dw,@DateStart) not in (1,7)
        BEGIN
            SET @DateStart = @DateStart+1
            SET @CounctDays = @CounctDays-1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @DateStart = @DateStart+1
        END
    END

    SET @DateEnd = @DateStart

    IF DATEPART(dw,@DateEnd) in (1,7)
        BEGIN
        IF DATEPART(dw,@DateEnd) = 1
        BEGIN
            SET @DateEnd = @DateEnd +1
        END
        IF DATEPART(dw,@DateEnd) = 7
        BEGIN
            SET @DateEnd = @DateEnd +2
        END
    END
END

-- выводим полученный результат
SELECT @DateEnd [Result]
```

Comment: дело в том, что решение с использованием циклов как раз не подходит в силу того, что рассчет нужно произвести в теле sql инструкции, с применением циклов придется выносить в отдельню функцию

Comment: @user3132346 о какой инструкции вы говорите? Вы можете взять предложенный код вставить в хранимую процедуру, что правильно, не дублировать же куски идетичного кода повсюду, можете и просто в свой скрипт вставить, заменив ваш кусок и имена переменных.

Comment: я говорю о динамическом sql, который формируется кодом, и выполняется на пользовательской базе  (которых сотни) с ограниченными правами и ролями, и для того чтоб сделать просчет придется пихать SP или UDF так в каждую базу. Этот вариант не подходит, иначе я бы не искал способ решения без циклов, что и  указано в заколовке

Answer (score 0):

[Посмотрите данное решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11435423/adding-some-date-excluding-saturday-and-sunday-using-sql-server).

Как по мне ответ @Martin Devillers является решением.

Я проверил для Вашего случая:
'2018/03/03' (суббота) + 2 дня (понедельник, вторник) = среда (2018-03-07)

Comment: а почему среда а не вторник?))   DATEADD(dd,2, '2018/03/05')  дает 7е чсило,  это понедельник (рабочий день), значит добавляя к выходному 2 дня я должен получить 2й день по счету а не 3й - то-есть 6е число для моего случая